# How to get the Value of XElement

Tags: c#

I am parsing through an xml doc and I need to get the value of a `Property` element. As of right now I have a line of code that returns this:

```
<Property name="ID" value="thevalueineed"/>
```

Here is my line of code used.

```
var ID = from el in linkedinfo.DescendantsAndSelf("Property") 
         where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "ID" 
         select el.Attributes("value").ToString();
```

What would be the next step I am missing that would I get `thevalueineed` from that Element that I have in `var ID`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your `select` as

```
select (string)el.Attribute("value")
```

A working code.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root><Property name=""ID"" value=""thevalueineed""/></root>");

var ID = from el in xDoc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf("Property")
            where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "ID"
            select (string)el.Attribute("value");

var val = ID.First();
```

Comment: I did as you said and it does not return the correct value. Instead it returns `[0] = "System.Xml.Linq.XElement+<GetAttributes>d__0"`

Comment: are you sure you changed Attribute(s) to Attribute ?

Comment: Thank you this did work. I had to lose the is in `.Attributes` and make it `Attribute`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var ID = from el in linkedinfo.Descendants("Property") 
         where el.Attribute("name").Value == "ID" 
         select el.Attribute("value").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `.Value` instead of casting to string:

```
XElement linkedTeethInfo = XElement.Parse(@"<Property name=""ID"" value=""thevalueineed""/>");

var ID = from el in linkedTeethInfo.DescendantsAndSelf("Property") 
    where el.Attribute("name").Value == "ID" 
    select el.Attribute("value").Value;

Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", ID.First());
```

Created a small fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrSITM

Comment: `I would personally use .Value instead of casting to string` Why? if `value` attribute doesn't exist, it would throw exception, hiding where you get that error. Casting would return null.

Comment: Valid point. Casting might save you, but depending on the requirements you would rather have an Exception then a 'silent' failover

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this method when reading XML files but I don't know if it will work with your XML file.

```
// Create a DataSet
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// Get the data from the XML file
ds.ReadXml("C:\\myXMLFile.xml");

// Get values
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string value = dr["ID"].ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select el.Attributes("value")
```

will return an a type

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute>>
```

try this:

```
var ID = element.DescendantsAndSelf("Property").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "id").Select(x => x.Attribute("value")).First();
```